# SailsJS / Waterline : Get only specific attributes from association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to get only the serialNumber of the tags associated to my Site model. Here is what i'm doing:

```
const site = await Site.findOne({
    id: siteId
}).populate('tags', { select: ['serialNumber'] });
```

It doesn't work. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: What DB u use? what type of association? Did u try populate without select? Your code you wrote is correct..

Comment: Does it throw an error? Or happens exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First it seems Models needs for populate select to work

```
schema: true
```

And then also it will only ignore other normal attributes

Means It will still return primary key field of tags and other associative attributes also.